# Search through NSString using Regular Expression

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

How might I go about searching/enumerating through an `NSString` using a regular expression?

A regular expression such as: `/(NS|UI)+(\w+)/g`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Example inspired in the documentation:

```
NSString *yourString = @"";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(NS|UI)+(\\w+)"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    // your code to handle matches here
}];
```

Comment: This is the code I am using including the string, https://gist.github.com/728216. However it doesn't work and the `NSLog`'s are not called.

Comment: I have checked that `(NS|UI)+(\w+)` is a valid regular expression on http://www.regextester.com/.

Comment: You need to double-escape those backslashes.

Comment: You mean `\w`? That is a meta character which will match a word character.

Comment: Joshua - `\w` is indeed the correct meta character, but the backslash character is used in normal strings as an escape character. The compiler's string parser will change `\w` to simply `w` before it is ever passed to the RegEx object. Run an NSLog to see for yourself. The correct notation is therefore `\\w`, as the compiler will convert '\\' to '\'. This convention is present in many languages.

Comment: Would someone mind to edit the answer and set `\\w` (instead of `\w`), I'm no Obj-C expert (yet) so I won't do it - but it is misleading to let a wrong answer as *accepted* for so long, if the backslash truly deserves to be doubled.

Answer (score 37):

If you just want to match some pattern in string, there is a simple way to test Regular Expression with `NSString`:

#### ObjC

[`rangeOfString:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-rangeofstring/)

```
NSString *string = @"Telecommunication";

if ([string rangeOfString:@"comm" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound)

    NSLog(@"Got it");

else

    NSLog(@"No luck");
```

---

Note, often you'll want ...

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"cOMm"
  options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location
  != NSNotFound)
     NSLog(@"yes match");
```

---

#### Swift 4

```
let string = "Telecommunication"

if string.range(of: "cOMm", options: [.regularExpression, caseInsensitive]) != nil {
    print("Got it")
} else {
    print("No luck")
}
```

Please take note that Swift's [`range(of:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-range) returns `Range<String.Index>?` that returns nil if search failed.

(in Swift 2, the name was `rangeOfString(_:options:)`)

Comment: `NSRegularExpressionSearch` isn't among the documented options, are you sure it's ok to do this?

Comment: Actually, you still can use this code snippet in Objective-C code but in Swift it should be NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it is well documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringcompareoptions