# How to check if string matches a regular expression in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, regexkitlite

since regular exressions are not supported in Cocoa I find [**RegexKitLite**](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html#RegexKitLiteOverview) very usefull.
But all examples extract matching strings.

I just want to test if a string matches a regular expression and get a Yes or No.

How can I do that?

Comment: Regular expressions 'not supported in Cocoa'? `NSRegularExpression` has been part of the framework since the release of iOS 4.0, almost a year before this question was asked, and there have apparently been methods that made use of regexes since before `NSRegularExpression` was introduced, as touched upon in, for instance, Vaz's answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I've used NSPredicate for that purpose:

```
NSString *someRegexp = ...; 
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", someRegexp]; 

if ([myTest evaluateWithObject: testString]){
//Matches
}
```

Comment: thanks, can I use default regular expression syntax for someRegexp?

Comment: I think yes, e.g. I used that for simple email validation: NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

Comment: @Vladimir that email regex is inadequate. Email addresses may contain unicode and top level domains are not 2 to 4 characters long.

Comment: It served my purpose and I had no complaints from users :) But you can easily replace it with better one, as it is not part of this question anyway

Answer (score 27):

Another way to do this, which is a bit simpler than using `NSPredicate`, is an almost undocumented option to NSString's [`-rangeOfString:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:) method:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"^\\w+$" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL matches = range.location != NSNotFound;
```

I say "almost undocumented", because the method itself doesn't list the option as available, but if you happen upon the documentation for the Search and Comparison operators and find [`NSRegularExpressionSearch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRegularExpressionSearch) you'll see that it's a valid option for the `-rangeOfString...` methods since OS X 10.7 and iOS 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

NSRegularExpression is another option:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`-isMatchedByRegex:`](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html#NSString_RegexKitLiteAdditions__-isMatchedByRegex%3a) method.

```
if([someString isMatchedByRegex:@"^[0-9a-fA-F]+:"] == YES) { NSLog(@"Matched!\n"); }
```

Comment: NB that is not part of cocoa.  very simple answer here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression

Comment: Well, @Vladimir's answer seems more simple to me.

Comment: `== YES` is redundant

Comment: Not a great idea to use this library just to perform a very simple action included in Cocoa.