# Find all locations of substring in NSString (not just first)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, substring

There is a substring that occurs in a string several times. I use `rangeOfString`, but it seems that it can only find the first location. How can I find all the locations of the substring?

```
NSString *subString1 = @"</content>";
NSString *subString2 = @"--\n";
NSRange range1 = [newresults rangeOfString:subString1];
NSRange range2 = [newresults rangeOfString:subString2];
int location1 = range1.location;
int location2 = range2.location;
NSLog(@"%i",location1);
NSLog(@"%i",location2);
```

Comment: please make your question more clear...

Comment: I would look at [NSRegularExpressions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `rangeOfString:options:range:` and set the third argument to be beyond the range of the first occurrence. For example, you can do something like this:

```
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0,string.length);
NSRange foundRange;
while (searchRange.location < string.length) {
    searchRange.length = string.length-searchRange.location;
    foundRange = [string rangeOfString:substring options:0 range:searchRange];
    if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        // found an occurrence of the substring! do stuff here
        searchRange.location = foundRange.location+foundRange.length;
    } else {
        // no more substring to find
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that substring appearances do not overlap, which is reasonable considering the question. In general it may not be a reasonable assumption. Consider the haystack "ababab". The needle "abab" appears at position 0 and at position 2 (overlapping the needle at position 0). Position 2 would be ignored by the above algorithm.

Comment: Changing the text "+foundRange.length" to the text "+1" modifies the algorithm in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0**

Find all locations of substring **`i`**

```
let text = "This is the text and i want to replace something"
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

var searchRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count)
var foundRange = NSRange()
while searchRange.location < text.characters.count {
    searchRange.length = text.characters.count - searchRange.location
    foundRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "i", options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: searchRange)
    if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        // found an occurrence of the substring! do stuff here
        searchRange.location = foundRange.location + foundRange.length
        mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: foundRange)
    }
    else {
        // no more substring to find
        break
    }
}

//Apply
textLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

And this output-

[image]

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. Basically, the algorithm traverses the string looking for substring matches and returns those matches in an array.

Since an **NSRange** is a struct it cannot be added to the array directly. By using **NSValue**, I can *encode* the match first and then add it to the array. To retrieve the range, I then *decode* the **NSValue** object to an **NSRange**.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSRange makeRangeFromIndex(NSUInteger index, NSUInteger length) {
    return NSMakeRange(index, length - index);
}

NSArray<NSValue *> * allLocationsOfStringMatchingSubstring(NSString *text, NSString *pattern) {
    NSMutableArray *matchingRanges = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSUInteger textLength = text.length;
    NSRange match = makeRangeFromIndex(0, textLength);

    while(match.location != NSNotFound) {
        match = [text rangeOfString:pattern options:0L range:match];
        if (match.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&match withObjCType:@encode(NSRange)];
            [matchingRanges addObject:value];
            match = makeRangeFromIndex(match.location + 1, textLength);
        }
    }

    return [matchingRanges copy];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *text = @"TATACCATGGGCCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCATCACAG";
        NSString *pattern = @"CAT";
        NSArray<NSValue *> *matches = allLocationsOfStringMatchingSubstring(text, pattern);

        NSLog(@"Text: %@", text);
        NSLog(@"Pattern: %@", pattern);
        NSLog(@"Number of matches found: %li", matches.count);

        [matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSValue *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSRange match;
            [obj getValue:&match];
            NSLog(@"   Match found at index: %li", match.location);
        }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithRange:match];` -- this looks easier than `value:withObjCType:`

Answer (score 1):

Passing nil to **[string rangeOfString:substring options:nil range:searchRange];** shows a warning.

To get rid of the warning, put in an enum from this group

```
enum {
   NSCaseInsensitiveSearch = 1,
   NSLiteralSearch = 2,
   NSBackwardsSearch = 4,
   NSAnchoredSearch = 8,
   NSNumericSearch = 64,
   NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch = 128,
   NSWidthInsensitiveSearch = 256,
   NSForcedOrderingSearch = 512,
   NSRegularExpressionSearch = 1024
};
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Search_and_Comparison_Options

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version in Swift 2.2 of PengOne's answer with input from kevinlawler and Gibtang

Note: string and substring are of type NSString

```
let fullStringLength = (string as String).characters.count
var searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, fullStringLength)
while searchRange.location < fullStringLength {
    searchRange.length = fullStringLength - searchRange.location
    let foundRange = string.rangeOfString(substring as String, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: searchRange)
    if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        // found an occurrence of the substring! do stuff here
        searchRange.location = foundRange.location + 1
    } else {
        // no more strings to find
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expression because it's a more declarative way and has fewer lines of code to write.

```c
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%@" options:nil error:nil];
NSString *toSearchStr = @"12312 %@ Text %@ asdsa %@";
__block int occurs = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:toSearchStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, toSearchStr.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
       occurs++;
}];
// occurs == 3
```