# is it possible to find every occurrence of a string in UITextView and attribute that occurrence?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I'm trying to find every occurrence of a string in UITextView and attribute that occurrence but i attributes the entire textView after the first occurrence of that string. Is it possible to find the location of each occurrence of "hello" and attribute them without attributing the entire textView

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

            if textView == self.textView {

        let nsString = textView.text as NSString
        let end = textView.text.characters.count
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, end) as NSRange

        let hString = nsString.rangeOfString("hello")
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)

        let cTv = textView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString


                if hString.length > 0{


           text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.magentaColor(), range: range)


                    cTv.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withAttributedString: text)

        }


                textView.attributedText = text

    }
    return true

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system sends `textView(_:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)` **before** it modifies `textView.text`. You would probably be better off implementing `textViewDidChange(_:)`, which the system sends **after** it modifies `textView.text`.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let text = textView.text as NSString
    let richText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text as String)
    var searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
    while true {
        let range = text.rangeOfString("hello", options: [], range: searchRange)
        if range.location == NSNotFound {
            break
        }
        richText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.magentaColor(), range: range)
        searchRange.location = range.location + range.length
        searchRange.length = text.length - searchRange.location
    }
    textView.attributedText = richText
}
```

Comment: +1. This solves all the problems in the OPs code. One thing (possibly), depending on the string the OP searches for. As suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033574/find-all-locations-of-substring-in-nsstring-not-just-first, adding 1 to the start of the search range makes sure that overlapping occurances of the string (if possible, depends on the string), are highlighted.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: it cites "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate"

Comment: and "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: I forgot to update `searchRange.location` in the loop. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with an array of Strings? I tried a for each loop inside the while loop but it never gets executed and the UITextView becomes disabled for some strange reason.

Comment: You would need a for loop around the `while` loop and the initialization of `searchRange`.