# How to get highlighted text range in WebView Content in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

Applied this code in .js file

```
var selectedText = "";
function getHighlightedString()
{
  var text = document.getSelection();
  startIndex = text.anchorOffset;
  endIndex = text.focusOffset;
  selectedText = text.anchorNode.textContent.substr(startIndex,endIndex - text.anchorOffset);
  var rangeText = document.getSelection().toString();
}
function highlight() {
 if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
  var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.appendChild(selectionContents);
  span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
  span.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(237,191,245)";
  span.style.color = "orange";
  range.insertNode(span);
 }
}
```

And I'm using this code for highlighting the text.

```
NSString *filePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *jsString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView_Detail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

NSString *highlightFunction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"highlight()"];
[webView_Detail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:highlightFunction];
highlightedString = [webView_Detail                                     stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

I stuck for getting the text range. it i have to send to server.but i couldn't able to get selected text range.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

```
NSString * strJS = @"window.getSelection().toString()";
NSString * strSelectedText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strJS];
NSString *plainText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.textContent"];
NSRange * rangeOfString = [plainText rangeOfString:strSelectedText];
```

You can try following alternate also

```
NSString *plainText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerText"];
```

If there are multiple matches found for selected text, please refer following link to find all ranges of occurrence.

[Find all locations of substring in NSString (not just first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033574/find-all-locations-of-substring-in-nsstring-not-just-first)

Comment: I didn't get range by using this. Would you give suggestion. strClassName is coming blank

Comment: I missed to add `toString()` so it should be `window.getSelection().toString()`

Comment: I need start range and end range, Here selected string coming.

Comment: I can't be able to get range

Comment: please check value of `plainText`

Comment: please check value of `plainText`

Comment: I got the the range. Now i want reselect that area according to range

Comment: Range method sometimes working or sometimes is not working

Comment: sometimes it gives me like this when i start from starting :location=9223372036854775807, length=0,some time correct

Comment: looks like it depends on the text you are selecting and text that HTML is having

Comment: I got the range of webview selected content, now i want to change the background of html content within range, server guys are sending range like this (58,1599). i want to change the background color and text color within this range in html content, Please help me