# Swift - search strings in TextView and make them bold

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an `UITextField` with long text inside, I need to find all the occurrences of a string inside the text and make them bold.
I know I should use `NSMutableAttributedString` for making the text bold, but how can I search specific substring inside the text?

Comment: This question may help: [Find all locations of substring in NSString (not just first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033574/find-all-locations-of-substring-in-nsstring-not-just-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a textView extension that can be called on your textView outlet:

```
extension UITextView {    
    func makeBold(originalText: String, boldText: String) {

        let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText)
        let boldRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: boldText)

        attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13), range: boldRange)
        self.attributedText = attributedOriginalText
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

textView.makeBold(originalText: "Make bold", boldText: "bold")
```

Comment: That works great, thanks a lot
Is there a way to take only full word occurrence? With this solution if I search "me" It gets bold also the value inside a work (e.g. mercy "me" gets bold but in this case should be avoided)

Comment: Check out the example in this answer for that and take note of the comments for your application https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033787/4844273