# NSString value validation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

This simple validation method for `NSString` makes trouble.
I have an `NSString` value and I want to validate the string, i.e, if the string contains **only 'a to z' (or) 'A to Z' (or) '1 to 9' (or) '@,!,&'** then the string is valid.  If the string contains any other values then this the `NSString` is invalid, how can i validate this..?

As example:

Valid:

```
NSString *str="aHrt@2"; // something like this
```

Invalid:

```
NSString *str="..gS$"; // Like this
```

Comment: Please note that the currently accepted answer allows for far more characters than desired including accented letters and letters from other alphabets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using character sets:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *set = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@!&"];
[set formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[set invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
    // contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and &@! only - valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: FYI - The `alphanumericCharacterSet` includes much more than a-z, A-Z, 0-9. From the docs: *Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as basic units of alphabets, syllabaries, ideographs, and digits.*

Answer (score 3):

I would do something using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`

Create an `NSCharacterSet` containing all valid characters, then trim those characters from the test string, if the string is now empty it is valid, if there are any characters left over, it is invalid

```
NSCharacterSet *validCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"myvalidchars"];
NSString *trimmedString = [testString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:validCharachters];
BOOL valid = [trimmedString length] == 0;
```

**Edit:**
If you want to control the characters that can be entered into a text field, use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` in `UITextFieldDelegate`

here the testString variable becomes the proposed string and you return YES if there are no invalid characters

Comment: I'm getting input from UITextfield, where user allowed only to type characters like this  'a to z' (or) 'A to Z' (or) '1 to 9' (or) '@,!,&'. I have used Regex but no result...any sample code friends..?

Answer (score 2):

The [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) class is what you want

[More info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) about predicate programming.  Basically you want "self matches" (your regular expression).  After that you can use the `evaluateWithObject:` method.

**EDIT** Easier way: (nevermind, as I am editing it wattson posted what I was going to)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class NSRegularExpression to do this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use NSRegularExpression to search your NSString, if it contains only the valid characters (or vice versa).

More info:

[Search through NSString using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression)

[Use regular expression to find/replace substring in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/user-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)validation:(NSString *)string  
{

   NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890abcdefghik"] invertedSet];
NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
return ([string isEqualToString:filtered]);
}
```

In your button action:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPress{

 if ([self validation:activity.text]) {
    NSLog(@"Macth here");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not Match here");
}
}
```

Replace this "1234567890abcdefghik" with your letters with which you want to match

Comment: he has to replace a-z, A-Z,0-9 and a total of 80 characters.... suggest some easier way. :)

Comment: I'm not matching anything... User can give any input but he can only type characters like  'a to z' (or) 'A to Z' (or) '1 to 9' (or) '@,!,&'

Comment: so you want user to type  only above listed characters into text field

Answer (score 1):

```
+(BOOL) validateString: (NSString *) string
{
    NSString *regex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z@!&]";
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",  emailRegex];
    BOOL isValid = [test evaluateWithObject:string];
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using `NSMutableCharacterSet`

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToKeep = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
[charactersToKeep addCharactersInString:@"@?!"];
NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [charactersToKeep invertedSet]
NSString *trimmed = [ str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove];
if([trimmed length] != 0)
{
  //invalid string
}
```

Reference [NSCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is basically a repeat of H2CO3's answer (with the same problem too).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex. If every thing fails use brute force like

```
 unichar c[yourString.length];
         NSRange raneg={0,2};
        [yourString getCharacters:c range:raneg];

// now in for loop

    for(int i=0;i<yourString.length;i++)
    {
     if((c[i]>='A'&&c[i]<='Z')&&(c[i]=='@'||c[i]=='!'||c[i]=='&'))
       {
         //not the best or most efficient way but will work till you write your regex:P
       }


    }
```