# How to find multiple substrings within braces from a string?

Tags: ios, string, swift3, substring

I have a string `[Desired Annual Income]  /([Income per loan %] /100)`

Using this string, I have to find two sub strings 'Desired Annual Income' and 'Income per loan %' in Swift3.

I am using below code to achieve this '[How do I get the substring between braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959157/how-do-i-get-the-substring-between-braces)':

```
  let myString = "[Desired Annual Income]  /([Income per loan %] /100)"
  let start: NSRange = (myString as NSString).range(of: "[")
  let end: NSRange = (myString as NSString).range(of: "]")
   if start.location != NSNotFound && end.location != NSNotFound && end.location > start.location {
      let result: String = (myString as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(location: start.location + 1, length: end.location - (start.location + 1)))          
      print(result)
   }
```

But as an output I am getting only 'Desired Annual Income', How can I get all substrings?

Comment: what the OP you expect

Comment: Output should be Desired Annual Income & Income per loan %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Hope it will work

```
let str = "[Desired Annual Income]  /([Income per loan %] /100)"
let trimmedString = str.components(separatedBy: "]")
for i in 0..<trimmedString.count - 1{ // not considering last component since it's of no use hence count-1 times loop
    print(trimmedString[i].components(separatedBy: "[").last ?? "")
}
```

Output:-

```
Desired Annual Income
Income per loan %
```

Comment: it will also output the leading and trailing characters before `[` and after `]`

Comment: @RatulSharker No it won't

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good use case for regular expressions (`NSRegularExpression`). The principle of regular expressions is to describe a "pattern" that you want to search in a string.

In that case you search something between two brackets.

The code is then:

```
    let str = "[Desired Annual Income]  /([Income per loan %] /100)"

    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\[(.+?)\\]", options: [.caseInsensitive]) {
        var collectMatches: [String] = []
        for match in regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)) {
            // range at index 0: full match (including brackets)
            // range at index 1: first capture group
            let substring = (str as NSString).substring(with: match.range(at: 1))
            collectMatches.append(substring)
        }
        print(collectMatches)
    }
```

For the explanation about regular expressions, there are plenty of tutorial on internet. But in very short:

`\\[` and `\\]`: opening and closing brackets characters (the double backslashes are because brackets have a meaning in regular expression, so you need to escape them. In a text editor one backslash is enough, but you need a second one because you are in a `String` and you need to escape the backslash to have a backslash.

`(.+?)` is a bit more complex: the parentheses are the "capture group", what you want to get. `.` means "any character", `+` one or more time, `?` after a `+` is the greedy operator, which means that you want the capture to stop ASAP. If you don't put it, your capture can be in your case "Desired Annual Income]  /([Income per loan %", depending of the regex library that you are using. Foundation seems to be greedy by default, that being said.

Regex are not always super easy/direct, but if you do often text processing, it's a very powerful tool to know.