# Find an 8 digit string within a string - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a string that's come out of an OCR library like so:

```
ALLee;YIeiqm Y E JOHNSON-TEST g jammima g 02345678 8;;Y_(____. g GHJ- 444 4333333333 * BAKERY -- Scones p ii
```

I want to search through this string and find the "02345678" part. This string can be anything but it is always 8 characters long and all the characters are together. How can I search through the string to find the 1st occurrence of an 8 character contant string without a space or character that isn't in the ranges of A to Z and 0 to 9?

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Use the regular expression: `[A-Za-z0-9]{8}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *yourString = @"ALLee;YIeiqm Y E JOHNSON-TEST g jammima g 02345678 8;;Y_(____. g GHJ- 444 4333333333 * BAKERY -- Scones p ii";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[A-Za-z0-9]{8}"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    // your code to handle matches here
}];
```

(code shamelessly nicked from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression)).

Comment: The regular expression should include letters too.

Comment: @rmaddy Doesn't he just want the sequence of numbers?

Comment: Read the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @rmaddy Many thanks - not the first time I've been caught out from not reading the whole question...