# Extract values and elements of anchor <a> tag in iOS

Tags: ios, parsing

I have an NSString

```
@"<a data-poload="/do/usertooltip?id=25203-75736572" data-placement="right">@Some Name</a>".
```

I want to extract the value between the `<a> </a>` tag. (i.e. @Some Name)
and the elements value (i.e `/do/usertooltip?id=25203-75736572,`
right`)
How can I do this in iOS?

Comment: Have you tried using Regular expressions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression

Comment: This may be helpful: "[Parsing HTML on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone)".

Comment: Hi @ahmedalkaff,Yes I've tried with regEx and NSScanner. Here is my regEx pattern. NSString *patter = @"(<)(a)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(-)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(=)(\")((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)(\\?)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(=)(\\d+)(-)(\\d+)(\")(\\s+)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(-)((?:[a-z][a-z]+)).*?(\".*?\")(>)(@)((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)).*?(<[^>]+>)"; I thing it is wrong with this pattern.

Comment: Hi @insertusernamehere, I have parsed my HTML text using NSHTMLTextDocumentType. This served my purpose to parse html. But I need to parse above string to get the elements value.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *patter = @"(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>";` Just used this regex and do some string operation extract the desired string. Problem is now solved.