# Is there a way to reverse %@ Text in an HTML string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

Sorry guys, I'm very new to web dev. I have the below string :

```
Mark sent $USD 100 to Olivia.
```

I'm getting this sentence in a `UIWebView`. So the string is essentially below:

```
NSString whatHappened = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Mark sent <b>%@</b> to %@", amount, receiver];

NSString receiver = "Olivia"
NSString amount = "$USD 100"
```

Now, I basically want it to be so that, the `$USD 100` is reversed, so it is: `100 $USD`. How can I possibly achieve this? I have multiple things to send too, such as `100 Apples` etc., so a simply reverse on the `amount` string won't work. Any suggestions on how I can change this in the HTML string?

Comment: I just happened to stumble across this question (I'm not sure how) and I'm not familiar with objective C, so I'll add a little to question:

Does [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Mark sent %@ %@ to %@", type, amount, receiver]; not work, so you could have NSString receiver="Olivia" NSString amount="100" and NSString type="$USD" ?  Again, not familiar.  Apologize if this is a terrible comment.

Comment: lol... no I cannot break it up. It's a server response that I get.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Like I said, unfamiliar (though I plan on learning).  Thanks for your understanding. :)

Comment: Can you post the code that reverses the amount string? Since you have said, '...a simply reverse on the amount string won't work.', then that part might be problematic.

Comment: I'm assuming a simple string reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You have three good options:

1) Regular expressions ([Search through NSString using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression))

2) just divide the string on the space:

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *currency = components[0];
NSInteger amount = [components[1] integerValue];
```

3) use NSScanner (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html) to convert the amount back into an NSNumber and reformat it that way.

```
NSString *formatString = @"$USD 0.0";
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setPositiveFormat:formatString];

NSNumber *amountValue = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:amount];
```

Then you can reformat it however you like:

```
if (amountValue != nil) {
    NSString *formattedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ $USD", amountValue];
}
```

Note that `amountValue` will equal `nil` if the string was not in the format that you specified to the formatter. This means that if you decide to send, for example, `@"100 Apples"` instead, you can easily detect it.

Your only challenge then would be identifying what the format of the incoming amount will be, if it has any likelihood of changing.