# Objective C String Manipulation

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, nsstring

I have the following NSString:

```
@"Show study NCT01287026: Real-time MRI Right Heart Catheterization Using Passive Catheters"
```

From this, I need to create 2 new strings. One would hold the 11 characters of the NTC code:

```
@"NCT01287026"
```

and the other the title of the study:

```
@"Real-time MRI Right Heart Catheterization Using Passive Catheters"
```

I have several similar strings. They all start with "Show study NTC********". What is the best way to go about this?

I can find the occurrence of "NTC", but I am not sure how to create the new string with the 8 other characters which come after it. I also need the rest of the string (study title) which varies in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *words = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@": "];
NSString *nct = [words[0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Show study " withString:@""];
NSString *title = words[1];
```

Take a look at the [*NSString Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) or the [*String Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i) to learn about the many useful messages you can send to a string.

Comment: Thank you. Will be voting on the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/index.html) for this:

```
NSString *string = @"Show study NCT01287026: Real-time MRI Right Heart Catheterization Using Passive Catheters";
NSString *nctString;
NSString *title;

NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"NCT" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@":" intoString:&nctString];
[scanner scanString:@": " intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet] intoString:&title];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first string using this regex: `\d{8}` ([regexr](http://regexr.com/3a2fh))

This works for the second string: `:.+` ([regexr](http://regexr.com/3a2fk))

You can use these to get the string like so:

```
NSString *string = @"Show study NCT01287026: Real-time MRI Right Heart Catheterization Using Passive Catheters";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\d{8}"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    //first match
}];
```

From: [Search through NSString using Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353834/search-through-nsstring-using-regular-expression)

And repeat to using the second regex.